# xpath in asp.net c# web appication selection multiple values in xmldocument.selectnodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml document like this...  this xml doc provides content for webpages

```
<pages id="pages">
  <page id="Shipping-Services">
    <linktext>Shipping Services</linktext>
    <pagelink>Shipping-Services</pagelink>
     <content>Shipping Services</content>
     <H1>Shipping Services</H1>
     <LogoALT>Shipping Services</LogoALT>
     <Title>Shipping Services</Title>
     <Desc>Shipping Services</Desc>
     <KeyWords>My, Key, Words</KeyWords>
     <banner></banner>
     <market>value</market>
   </page>
</pages>
```

I am trying to search based on page id and market using xmldocument.selectnodes

```
XmlDocument xdoc2 = new XmlDocument();
xdoc2.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xml/Pagesextend.xml"));
XmlNodeList xList2 = xdoc2.SelectNodes(".//*[@id='" + Request.QueryString[1].ToString() + "']");
```

tried this....  not working

```
 XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
 xdoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xml/Pages.xml"));
 XmlNodeList xList = xdoc.SelectNodes(".//*[@id='" + Request.QueryString["p"].ToString() + "' and contains(market, '" + Request.QueryString["m"].ToString() + "']");
```

I can search by ID no problem, but adding the second market parameter is stumping me...  Any assistance would be great.

what xpath would I enter to use two parameters how I have the xml setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the closing ')' on the contains.

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xml/Pages.xml"));
XmlNodeList xList = xdoc.SelectNodes(".//*[@id='" + Request.QueryString["p"].ToString() + "' and contains(market, '" + Request.QueryString["m"].ToString() + "')]");
```

I usually prefer to use string.Format() for XPath:

```
XmlNodeList xList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(string.Format(".//*[@id='{0}' and contains(market, '{1}')]", Request.QueryString["p"].ToString(), Request.QueryString["m"].ToString()));
```

Helps a bit when you need to look for minor syntax errors like missing parenthesis.

Comment: It worked!  I used your String.Format version, Thanks for your quick response...  seems so easy now :)